# Adding 0 to an IP address in C#

Tags: c#

I have an IP address: `192.168.1.1`. But I want to make it to become `192168001001`? How do we do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This depends completely on your representation. Is it a string? (I would assume it is, but you should specify anyway)

Comment: Not yet. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have like a gazzilion ideas but, still, have *you* tried anything?

Comment: @Duane, and for 192.168.1.2? :-)

Comment: Duane. I'm not referring to this IP address only. I want it to apply to all IP address.

Comment: Split by `.` and check length < 2 then add 0 or if length < 3 then add 00....

Comment: @Shai, just suggest the most simple way will do.

Comment: Split the string at the dot, pad it to three characters, and put the string together again without the dots.

Comment: Regex to replace dot-digit with dot-zero-zero-digit? There'll probably be edge cases to work out though

Comment: @Mario, then do I have to split the IP address string to 4 part and check it one by one?

Comment: @Duane, Maybe something like this `("."+string+".").Replace(".1.", ".001.").Replace(".2.",".002").bla-bla-bla.Replace(".99.",".099.").Replace(".","");`

Comment: @maniac84 Yes, please check Nikhil Agrawal's answer or ykatchou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string sIp = "192.168.0.1";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sIp.Split('.').ToList().ForEach(u => sb.Append(u.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')));

// sb.ToString(); contains the result
```

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal, thanks for the edit but what exactly is the point in removing 2 blank spaces...?

Comment: @Shai Maybe getting the [Copy Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badge? :-)

Comment: @Shai he added a second `;` to the last line of my answer, too :)

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
var formattedIP = String.Concat("192.168.1.1".Split('.').Select(x => x.PadLeft(3, '0')));
```

Comment: Explanation for the down-vote?

Comment: There's a serial downvoter here.. lol

Answer (score 3):

For me, the cleanest way is this one :

Direct answer :

```
//String version
string sIP = "192.168.1.1";
string sOut = "";

foreach(string sPart in sIP.Split('.')){
   sOut = string.format("{0}{1:000}", sOut, sPart);
}

//IPAddress version
IPAddress oIP = new IPAddress("192.168.1.1");
string sOut = oIP.GetAddressBytes.ToString();
```

Keep in mind to always use the IPAddress class for parsing/checking/manipulating IP :).
Because you should be able to use IPv4 and IPv6 address !

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx

Comment: and here I can see a much better answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "192.168.1.1";
string[] split = input.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

string result = string.Join(string.Empty, split.Select(s => s.PadLeft(3, '0')));
```

Comment: @downvoters may I know whats wrong?

Comment: Really don't like when somebody downvotes without commenting why...

Comment: Not a down-voter but... why are you removing empty entries?

Comment: @NPSF3000 In this case, there is no need, but I'm accustomed to always include this option when I'm splitting strings where the delimiters are within the string and not at the beginning or the end.

Comment: Be warned, that not all formats include the 0's IIRC... so it could lead to incorrect formatting.

Comment: @NPSF3000 is this a comment on this answer or the question?

Comment: To this answer.  If the input string was "127...1" you'd only output 127001.  Just thought I'd mention it is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str1 = "192.168.1.1";

string[] str = str1.Split('.');

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    str[i] = int.Parse(str[i]).ToString("000");

str1 = string.Join("", str);
```

Now `str1` contains `"192168001001"`

Comment: String are immutable and the value in the array is not updated in the for each loop. Regular for loop and update the value in the array.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: Done. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
string ip = "192.168.12.1";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
string[] array = ip.Split('.');

foreach (string subsection in array)
{
      if (subsection.Length < 2)
             stringBuilder.Append("00" + subsection);
      else if (subsection.Length < 3)
             stringBuilder.Append("0" + subsection);
      else
             stringBuilder.Append(subsection);
}
```

Comment: see my comment on the question. This does not work, it only works for the input string, but not for 192.168.12.1 or 192.168.2.2

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It looks like he only wants to replace single instances of "1" with "001". `192.168.1.1. But I want to make it to become 192168001001` which this does.

Comment: Comment from above: "Duane. I'm not referring to this IP address only. I want it to apply to all IP address. – maniac84 18 mins ago". So actually no, it's not about replacing `1` by `001`

Comment: Yes I know? And how does that invalidate this answer? In his example he's replacing 1's with 001, this satisfies the requirement. Can you explain how this doesn't work for `192.168.12.1`? (protip: it does). Obviously it won't work for `192.168.2.2` because there are no single occurances of `1` in the string so it will just return `192.168.2.2`. Perhaps you should actually try this code out...

Comment: It does work for 192.168.12.1 but 192.168.0012.001 is not a format you would use, though. And it invalidates the answer because the OP does not want to know how to replace a single `1` by `001` but to have IPs like xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa and not xxx.yyy.z.a .

Comment: It will return `19216812001` and not the string you've quoted, again, i would urge you to try the code before commenting. And op wants this without dots `.` too.... He wasn't clear enough in his question. I have edited to reflect this change. Hopefully this resolves the issue and you can remove the -1 :)

Comment: Yes, of course 19216812001. But that wouldn't be the right return value, too. The last edit looks correct in terms of what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string FormatIP(string ip)
{
   string[] data = ip.Split('.');
   if (data.Length > 4)
      throw new Exception("Invalid IP address");
   List<string> finalIP = new List<string>();
   int intChunk;
   string temp;
   foreach (string chunk in data)
   {
       temp = chunk;
       if (temp.Length > 3 || int.TryParse(temp, out intChunk) == false || intChunk > 255)
           throw new Exception("Invalid IP address");
       while (temp.Length < 3)
           temp = "0" + temp;
       finalIP.Add(temp);
    }
    data = finalIP.ToArray();
    return string.Join(".", data);
}
```